# ggplot2 histogram with table(); without scaling of the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

My question can be posed two-fold: How to make `ggplot()` work with `table` objects? In case it's not possible: How can I,  with `ggplot()`, plot a histogram of data.frame with discrete counts and gaps such that the x axis doesn't collapses (i.e. gaps are not shown)?

Here is the data:

```
dat <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/fish.csv")
dat[[3,"child"]] <- 400 # for illustration purpose

frqncy <- as.data.table(table(dat$child)) # because a table object is not understood
```

I was running

```
ggplot(frqncy, aes(x=V1, y= Freq)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

but 400 and 3 are right next to each other.

EDIT: Henrik suggests to make sure that `frqncy$V1` is `numeric`. Indeed, it is a string when it comes out of `table()`. Hence I do

```
frqncy$V1 <- as.numeric(frqncy$V1)
ggplot(frqncy, aes(x=V1, y= N)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

which returns the desired plot but also a warning message:

```
Warning message:
position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

Why is that?

Comment: Make sure that Var1 is `numeric`. If it is, I think you will get the desired plot with a continuous x axis.

Comment: Running your code gives quite some space between 87 and 322 in the plot. So, what is the problem?

Comment: @Jaap: You are right, the above code works. I didn't check it. The fact why it didn't work with my code is as pointed out by @Henrik: Rereading the data like in my question makes Var `numeric`, which it wasn't when I just take the table. I am going to change the data in the example to illustrate the point.

Comment: Are you using `data.frame(table(some_vector))` to convert the resultant table into a data frame?